# Rails 2 + Paperclip + ImageMagick in Linux is not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, imagemagick, paperclip

I set up a app in windows using paperclip and imagemagick and it works fine.

Now, I had to migrate this APP to linux.

I already have paperclip's gem and imagemagick but I can't make it work.

I keep getting this message when saving the image:

> sh: identify: command not found

Why? Am I missing something?

Thank you!

ps: I'm able to run the "identify" command from my app's directory.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean it works fine on Linux and is broken on Windows?  I've never seen a fully functional ImageMagick windows installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `config/environments/development.rb` file (or production if necessary) you can add Paperclips command_path option:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/opt/local/bin'
```

You will want to replace /opt/local/bin with the directory path returned typing in your command line:

```
$ which identify
```